# Chrome extension not recognizing identity

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, identity

I am trying to get use chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo
I found my key using Chrome Extension Source Viewer and added it to my manifest.json file and under permissions added identity

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "identity", "identity.email"],
```

But I am getting a `Cannot read property 'getProfileUserInfo' of undefined` when I try to run the method.
I printed out `chrome` and go this
[image]

It seems that chrome picked up `"storage"`but not `"identity"`
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The `identity` permission adds `chrome.identity` to your *background* script, but not your content script. You don't say where you printed chrome from, but if it was from your content script, I would expect to see `storage`, but not `identity`.

Once you get that working, the `identity.email` permission *may* populate the user's email address, but I found that it only works if the user is logged in **and** has Chrome Sync switched on.